# MGo Regex query returns empty result

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have been using the following code to list users starting with a search keyword which is passed to the function as `name`.

```
func (this *user) GetUsersByEmailOrName(name *string) ([]types.User, error) {
formattedName := "/^" + *name + "/"

var ors []bson.M
userNameOr := bson.M{
    "user_name": bson.M{
        "$regex": bson.RegEx{formattedName, "i"},
    },
}
ors = append(ors, userNameOr)

nameOr := bson.M{
    "name": bson.M{
        "$regex": bson.RegEx{formattedName, "i"},
    },
}
ors = append(ors, nameOr)

query := bson.M{
    "$or": ors,
}

fmt.Println(query)
s := this.Database.Session.Copy()
defer s.Close()

var users []types.User
err := s.DB("").C(this.Collection).Find(query).Sort("name").All(&users)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Println(users)
return users, nil
}
```

I am fairly new to GoLang and MGo. I am not sure what went wrong. Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Can you show your function prototype?   What type is `name`, in particular?

Comment: @BadZen I have updated the question with the function prototype.